# Authenticate to Office 365 from local ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, office365, adfs

I have a local ASP.net portal that is integrated with my local Active Directory. My users are able to SSO from this portal to the related applications (HR, Finance etc)

Now we will put one more button called "Mail" on the portal. I want that once user (domain joined or not) click that button, I will authenticate it using local LDAP and SSO to Office 365 Outlook portal.

Dirsync and ADFS already set up for users. They are pointing sts portal and uses local AD passwords to authenticate office 365.

To integrate this solution into my portal, what steps should I follow?
Should I integrate with ADFS or Office 365? Which code samples can I use to start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add WIF to your portal and point it to your ADFS instance.

Then you will be able to SSO to any application inside Azure Active Directory - which includes Office 365.